# ajax form submission with php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submission

I am having trouble getting the email to send which I am sure it is because of the php but here is the js ajax also..it shows my error messages for form fields that are not filled out correctly and then it shows my processing bar once submitted but I get my error message after submission..any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<form method="post" action="feedback.php" id="contactform">
            <fieldset class="first">


            <div id="response"></div>  


            <div id="name_input">

            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="required" type="text" maxlength="128" />

            </div>



            <div id="email_input">

            <input id="email" name="name" placeholder="Email"  class="required" type="text"  maxlength="128" />

            </div>



            <div id="budget_input">
            <label for="budget">Budget</label>
            <select id="mydropdown">
            <option value="none" selected=“”> -- choose one --</option>
            <option value="firstchoice">$0 - $1,000</option>
            <option value="secondchoice">$1,000 - $2,000</option>
            <option value="thirdchoice">$3,000 +</option>
            </select>
            </div>



            <div id="button">

            <input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="" />
            </div>


            </fieldset>


        </form>
```

Updated:

```
<?php 

$name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));           
$email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
$mydropdown = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mydropdown'])));  
$recipient = "blake.harrison1@cox.net";  
$humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];



    if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) { 

    //Validate data and return success or error message
    $error_message = '';    
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";

    if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";             
    }
    if (empty($name)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your name.</p>";              
    }

    if (empty($mydropdown)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>Please select an item from the list.</p>";
    }               

    if (!empty($error_message)) {
                $return['error'] = true;
                $return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.</h3>".$error_message;                 
                echo json_encode($return);
                exit();
        } else {

        //send to  an email


        $emailSubject = 'Top Contact Form';
        $webMaster = 'blake.harrison1@cox.net';

 $body="
 <br><hr><br>
 <strong>Name:</stong> $name <br>
 <br>
 <strong>Email:</stong> $email <br>
 <br>
 <strong>Budget:</strong> $mydropdown <br>
 <br>
 ";      

        $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


        //send email and return to user
        if(mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {

            $return['error'] = false;
            $return['msg'] = "<p>Message sent successfully. Thank you for your interest " .$name .".</p>"; 
            echo json_encode($return);
        }
    }   
 } else {

$return['error'] = true;
$return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h3>";  
echo json_encode($return);
 }

?> 



$(document).ready(function() {

$('form #response').hide();

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // prevent forms default action until
    // error check has been performed
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab form field values
    var valid = '';
    var required = ' is required.';
    var name = $('form #name').val();
    var email = $('form #email').val();
    var mydropdown = $('form #mydropdown').val();
    var honeypot = $('form #honeypot').val();
    var humancheck = $('form #humancheck').val();


    // perform error checking
    if (name == '' || name.length <= 2) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';  
    }

    if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
        valid += '<p>Your email' + required +'</p>';                                                  
    }

    if (mydropdown == '') {
        valid += '<p>An item from the list' + required +'</p>';

    }

    if (honeypot != 'http://') {
        valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';    
    }

    if (humancheck != '') {
        valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>'; 
    }


    // let the user know if there are erros with the form
    if (valid != '') {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
            .html('<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' +valid).fadeIn('fast');           
    }
    // let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
    // serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
    else {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('slow');                                      

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData);           
    }           

});
});


function submitForm(formData) {

$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send.php',        
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 12000,
    success: function(data) {           

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast'); 

        if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {

            setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 12000);
        }

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +
                          '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +
                          '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');           
    },              
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            

        $('form')[0].reset();
    }
}); 
};
```

Comment: what is the exact message you are getting back from the ajax request?

Comment: i get a timeout condition or sometimes i get "Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.
A valid email address is required.
A message is required."

Comment: semi new to php, thought I read somewhere it was for offline purposes, I removed it but no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try $.post instead of $.ajax

```
$.post(url, {argument_name: value, ...} , function(data){

// callback function..

}, 'json'}
```

Comment: so you mean just$.post({ 
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'feedback.php',  
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  timeout: 7000,
  success: function(data) {

Comment: changed it to post though and now it just continues to say processing but still with no email submission

Comment: no, try this 
    $.post("feedback.php", {name: value_to_be_posted, email:     email_to_be_posted, message: message_to_be_posted}, fucntion(data){}, 'json'}

Comment: you can take alook for some live examples here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: ok ill have to toy around with it for a bit and see what I can get working..thank you for the reference

Comment: please let me know if any help needed

Comment: and please mark it as solved if everything is working for you.

Comment: still workin on it Im trying out multiple solutions, I will once i got it functioning, thanks again

Comment: hey can you go here.. www.internetmarketingtrio.com/contact/ and fill out the form and submit it and tell me how I am supposed to get a div that is called upon by jquery to center that processing text by any chance..maybe there is an easy solution

Comment: @Blake your code is a little bit fuzzy, I might find some logical errors in it. But still i'm not pretty sure about the errors because I've tried it three times and in the first time I got 502 error then I got aborted in the third time I got success so, give me more resources so I can test it.. and I didn't find the upon div.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response I saw the emails this morning..I updated my code up top..I believe that it is only the top banner contact forms that are throwing the errors and that the contact page is working now so I put the code for that up there

Answer (score 0):

do this with the php page...

```
  sleep(2);
  //Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
  $name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));           
  $email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
  $message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']))); 
  $recipient = "info@internetmarketingtrio.com";



//Validate data and return success or error message
$errors = array();   
$reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";

if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

            $errors[] = "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";             
}
if (empty($name) || $name == '') {

            $errors[] = "<p>Please provide your name.</p>";              
}           
if (empty($message) || $message == '') {

            $errors[] = "<p>A message is required.</p>";
}
if(empty($errors)) {
    $return['success'] = true;
    $return['message'] = "<p>Thanks for your feedback " .$name. ".</p>";
} else {
    $return['success'] = false;
    $return['message'] = "<h3>Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.</h3>";
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        $return['message'] .= $error ."<br />";
    }
}
```

And then in your call to get this page... the ajax call...

```
$.ajax({    
type: 'POST',
url: 'feedback.php',        
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(data) { 
    if(data.success) {
        $("form#response").removeClass().addClass('success').html(data.message).fadeIn('fast');
        removeResponse(5000);
    } else {
        $("form#response").removeClass().addClass('error').html(data.message).fadeIn('fast'); 
    }
}        
}); 

function removeResponse(time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("form#response").fadeOut('fast');
    }, time);
}
```

And that should do ya

Comment: hmm its still just sitting on that processing blue box and giving me no success class that i added or an email:(

Comment: are you running in chrome? if so before hitting submit hit F12 and open to the network tab, then hit submit, and you should see your php page appear there. click on it, then click on preview and paste the output here please

Comment: interesting, it is not giving me any kind of output preview

Comment: is the page name red in your network tab? if not then the php isn't finishing at all or is quietly erroring out. if the page isn't red then at the top of your php page add   error_reporting(E_ALL); oh and on a side note remove that sleep(2)

Comment: Notice  Undefined index: email in D:\hosting\10203437\html\feedback.php on line 4

Notice  Undefined index: message in D:\hosting\10203437\html\feedback.php on line 5

Comment: ok, then I need to see the html that you are using for the form. It sounds like you aren't sending the info properly. or on your php page in the first line add... echo "<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST)."</pre>"; and then paste the output. either way works fine

Comment: Array
(
    [name] => blake.harrison1@cox.net
    [mydropdown] => none
    [name_bot] => 
    [email_bot] => 
    [comment] => 
)
<pre>1</pre>

Comment: and i added the html to the top

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the bottom of my php ended up fixing my issue if anyone reads this

```
        $emailSubject = 'Contact Form';
        $webMaster = 'blake.harrison1@cox.net';

$body="
<br><hr><br>
<strong>Name:</stong> $name <br>
<br>
 <strong>Email:</stong> $email <br>
 <br>
 <strong>Message:</stong> $message 
";      

        $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


        //send email and return to user
        if(mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {

            $return['error'] = false;
            $return['msg'] = "<p>Message sent successfully. Thank you for your intrest " .$name .".</p>"; 
            echo json_encode($return);
        }
    }   
} else {

$return['error'] = true;
$return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h3>";  
echo json_encode($return);
 }

 ?>
```