# jQuery ajax doen't have success

Tags: php, ajax

I have a piece of HTML code:

```
<div id="question_form">
<form method="POST" id="question_form" action="addQuestion.php">
<input type="hidden" id="u_id" name="u_id" value="6"/>
<input type="hidden" id="u_a_name" name="u_a_name" value=""/>
<textarea placeholder="question here" cols="138" rows="3" name="question" id="question_input"/>
<input type="image" class="ask_button" value="submit" src="img/ask.png"/>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is JavaScript:

```
$(".ask_button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "addQuestion.php",
               data: $("div#question_form").formSerialize() + "&textareadata="+escape($("#question_input").value),
               success: function(data)
               {
                        if (data == "Asked") {
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
               }
             });
        return false;
    });
```

The php file checks is question is empty and if not - writes it into database.

When I click on submit button I see the addQuestion.php page, not alert, though php script is executed correctly. What can be a problem?

Comment: When you say you "see the addQuestion.php page" are you saying you see the php code, or its output?

Comment: Ofc output. It just echos `Asked`.

Comment: The code above tells the page to reload if it works, not alert. Try moving your alert into the true block of your `if` statement.

Comment: Yes. But no alerts and no reloadings. It is just stuck on `addQuestion.php` instead of AJAX catch the "Asked" echo.

Answer (score 1):

`escape($("#question_input").value)` should be `encodeURIComponent($("#question_input").val())`

The jQuery object has no value property(use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead) which is causing an error in your code and presumably causing the form to submit to `addQuestion.php`

---

You also have two `id` tags with the same name:

```
<div id="question_form">
<form method="POST" id="question_form" action="addQuestion.php">
```

Each `id` tag must be completely unique in the HTML for jQuery to supply expected results. Try renaming one of them.

Comment: Unfortuantely it didn't help. Still I see the addQuestion.php page :(

Comment: @JohnWilliam also what's `.formSerialize()`

Comment: that's equivalent for `.serialize()`, but it's needed for parsing textarea data, cuz it's applied on parent of form.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this similar issue here

[ajax form submission with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924309/ajax-form-submission-with-php/13924367#13924367)

Which is already solved by me.
And hope that will help you too.

Comment: Nice way of solving, but I really wanted my site to be made by one template.

Comment: Sure. But as long as you are using POST method in ajax. I prefer to use the jquery post function.  Anyway it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is solved. Really I used bad script so I changed `.value` to `.val()` and put all parametrs by hand, so now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a Javascript error that prevents the form from being sent via ajax, and it gets submitted with regular HTTP means.

You can not see the difference because form's `action` attribute is the same as ajax request url. If you change any of them you will notice what I explain.

To track the issue, you should enable "preserve logging upon navigation" or similar option in your firebug/firefox/chrome console, do the test again and see that the error pops in console exactly before you get navigated to `addQuestion.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this to avoid this type of issues,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ask_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "addQuestion.php",
           data: $("#question_form").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
                if (data == "Asked") {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                }
           }
         });
    return false;
});
```

});

and give different id for div and form...